# Search terms in other language turns out to question mark and symbols

Tags: search, language, encoding

I am facing one issue while i'm creating my website. I have a search bar on my website. I tried to type and search in chinese, but the search terms on page that i entered become question mark and symbol. The url also same. I'm wondering how can make it work. Only the search terms become this. Any solution?

**Updated:**
This is the search form that i have(this is a searchbox apply to my multisite).

```
<div class="search">
<form name="searchform" onsubmit="return !!(validateSearch() && dosearch());" method="get" id="searchform">
<input type="text" name="searchterms" class="terms" id="terms" placeholder="<?php if (is_search()) { ?><?php the_search_query(); ?><?php } elseif (is_home() || is_single() || is_page() || is_archive() || is_404()) { ?>What are you searching for?<?php } ?>">
<select name="sengines" class="state" id="state">
<option value="" selected>Select a State</option>
<?php $bcount = get_blog_count();
global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE spam = '0' AND deleted = '0' and archived = '0' and public='1'"));
if(!empty($blogs)){
    ?><?php
    foreach($blogs as $blog){
        $details = get_blog_details($blog->blog_id);
        if($details != false){
            $addr = $details->siteurl;
            $name = $details->blogname;
            if(!(($blog->blog_id == 1)&&($show_main != 1))){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $addr; ?>?s="><?php echo $name;?></option>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?><?php } ?>
</select>
<input name="Search" type="submit" value="Search" class="button3">
</form>

</div><!--search-->
```

**Javascript for the search form**

```
function dosearch() {
var sf=document.searchform;
var submitto = sf.sengines.options[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
window.location.href = submitto;
return false;
}

function validateSearch(){
    // set some vars
    var terms = document.getElementById('terms');
    var state = document.getElementById('state');
    var msg = '';

    if(terms.value == ''){
        msg+= 'We were unable to search without a keyword! \n';
    }

    else if(terms.value.length < 3){
        msg+= 'Keyword is too short! \n';
    }

    else if(terms.value.length > 25){
            msg+= 'Keyword is too long! \n';
    }

    else if(state.value == ''){
        msg+= 'Select state to proceed! \n';
    }


    // SUbmit form part
    if(msg == ''){
        return true;
    }else{
        alert(msg);
        return false;
    }

}
```

[image: This is the search result page(not completed yet!)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by myself.
What i have done is to get rid of something from the js code. Then, search terms in Chinese characters is successfully displayed.

Below is what has been removed from the code.

`var submitto = sf.sengines.options[sf.sengines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);`

I have removed the `escape`, so it works now!
Sometimes, we need to spend some of time to do the research.
Thank you for viewing my question and thank guys who tried to help! I appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `urldecode` on search string and your operations on decoded string.

Also check if you are using any other encoding, utf-8, utf-16.....

Comment: Yes! I'm using UTF-8. Only the search terms become worst after clicked the search button. The chinese characters(not the search terms) displaying properly on the page actually. Not sure why.

Comment: `echo utf8_decode(urldecode($_GET['s']));`

Comment: How to implement this to my search form?

Comment: This you can do in `search.php`, while querying posts

Comment: I'm not really good in php. Will you please show me the way how to do it? As i have the code for the form above. Thank you!